# Evaluating function using numpy array returns inf and nan

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy

I have the following numpy array and function:

```
import numpy
import scipy.special

i = numpy.linspace(0, 500, 501, dtype = int)

def func(x, n):
  return scipy.special.eval_hermite(n, x)
```

I evaluate the function for every element in my numpy array `i` using two different appraoches:

**Approach 1:**

```
hermites = func(0, i)
```

**Approach 2:**

```
hermites = [func(0, idx) for idx in i]
```

The two approaches result in two different answers. They are different because after element `50`, **approach 1** starts to return `inf` and `nan`. **Approach 2** also does not give the correct value for every element of `i`. However, it is able to calculate more of them. Approach 2 fails for `i >= 64`.

Both approaches give me an answer in approximately the same time (0.7 s for `len(i) = 15000`, determined using `timeit`). What I do not understand are the different results. This is because I learned to avoid `for loops` in python as much as possible. This does not seems to be the case this time.

The idea that it had to do with memory also crossed my mind. However, evaluating one single element, i.e. `print func(0, 64)` also returns `0.` (equal to the output of **approach 2**).

What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in scipy created by the occasionally surprising casting rules of numpy's "ufuncs".  The problem is that, in scipy version 0.16 and older, when the first argument of `eval_hermite` is an integer *array* and the second is an integer scalar, the data type of the return value is single precision floating point (`numpy.float32`).  When the second argument is a 64 bit floating point value, the return type is `numpy.float64`.  The largest value that can be represented with `float32` is much less than that of `float64`, so when the second argument is an integer, `eval_hermite` overflows to infinity much sooner.

For example, this is with scipy 0.16.0 and numpy 1.10.1:

```
In [26]: from scipy.special import eval_hermite
```

Note that the data type of the return value is `float32`:

```
In [27]: eval_hermite([20, 50, 100, 200], 0)
Out[27]: 
array([  6.70442586e+11,             -inf,              inf,
                    inf], dtype=float32)
```

If the second argument is floating point, the return type is `float64`, and the large values can be represented:

```
In [28]: eval_hermite([20, 50, 100, 200], 0.0)
Out[28]: 
array([  6.70442573e+011,  -1.96078147e+039,   3.06851876e+093,
         8.45055019e+216])
```

The work-around for your code is to always ensure that the second argument to `eval_hermite` is a floating point value.  For example,

```
hermites = func(0.0, i)
```

This issue has been fixed in the scipy development version (see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4896), so scipy 0.17 should not have this problem when it is released.

Comment: Should we edit the title?  The interesting part of the question isn't about "why inf and nan", but "why don't passing an array and using a listcomp to iterate element by element return the same results?"

Comment: Obtaining better results after upgrading to scipy 0.16.0. However, now for `i >= 270` I am again obtaining `inf` or `nan`. Has this bug been fully (all possible `i`) fixed in the scipy development version? And is there a way to obtain this version?

Comment: For `i >= 270`, the value of the Hermite polynomial at `x=0` is larger than can be represented with 64 bit floating point values, so `inf` is to be expected.  For `i >= 300`, I'm getting `nan`; I haven't looked into it, but I suspect some code ends up doing `inf - inf`.